# Equidistant sets and extremal points

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, functional-equations

Let $\lVert\cdot \rVert$ be **any** norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a point. Let $\textrm{ext}(B_{\lVert x\rVert})$  denote the set of all extremal points of $B_{\lVert x \rVert}:=\{y\in \mathbb{R}^n : \lVert x-y \rVert \leq \lVert x\lVert \} $. Suppose that there is a point $z\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that

$$\lVert x-se\rVert=\lVert z-se\rVert $$

for all real numbers $s\in [0,1]$ and all $e\in\textrm{ext}(B_{\lVert x\rVert})$.

Is it true that $x=z$?

In all possible examples I was able to imagine, this turned out to be the case. Unfortunately, I cannot think of a structured way to prove that the equality holds in general.

Comment: Same here: all examples I've tried lead to $z = x$. I deeply think the **Krein–Milman** Theorem should be helpful here (with slightly more hypotheses...) but I haven't had much success with it.

Comment: All I was able to show until now, is that the statement holds in $\mathbb{R}^2$. For this I used the Krein-Milman Theorem. I don't know enough convex geometry to proceed further.

Comment: I, too, have a sweet proof for the two-dimensional case with arguments from elementary geometry. Unfortunately, this proof won't work in higher dimensions. Since Krein--Milman is valid for all dimensions, it would be interesting to see your idea in detail.